Wordpress Issue, I can't see Edit Post tab
I was trying to edit the link of my website blog today. But I can't see the Edit Post tab that I normally use to do it. It was supposed to be on the left side of Edit with Elementor tab. It was there last time but when I tried it today, it wasn't there. What is the error? How can I fix it. Thanks


Have you tried turning off some of the other items in the bar? Any recent plugin updates or activations? Are you the only admin on the site? Possible someone else may have changed a setting to hide it. P.S.: if you hover over "Edit with Elementor," are there any additional links?
